# Find the field is mandatory or not

Tags: metadata-api, c#, required-field, partner-wsdl

I am developing an application for Salesforce integration. My requirement is to get all the validation rule and Mandatory fields from Lead category like we have lead status as mandatory in salesforce so I want both the Required field as well as validation rule for all the fields. I am making a use of PartnerWSDl as well as MetadataWSDL. Please help me in this regards. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at this topic: [Detect a required field in Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums?id=906F00000008x86IAA)

Comment: additionally: for validation rules you will never be able to get an automated way to process this, as they can contain whatever logic possible (e.g.: "this field is required for scenario a and for the combination of scenario b and c but not for scenario d"). Also there might be APEX trigger code as well that influences which fields should or should not be filled. If achievable, it would be better to retrieve the business logic from the functional design instead of trying to backwards-engineer it from the code.

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. I am using only ParterWSDL and MetadataWSDL, If I use the APEX then it would be an extra burden on application. Is it possible if I can try it with WSDL only, if not then I have to switch to APEX.